# I have a array of string have to find all the common character present from all strings

Tags: javascript

I have a array of string.

`let arr=["robin","rohit","roy"];`

Need to find all the common character present in all the strings in array.

**Output Eg: r,o**

I have tried to create a function for above case with multiple loops but i want to know what should be the efficient way to achive it.

Comment: loop through the array with for loop
compare first 2 elements find common elements 
then taking the common elements as an element, compare that and the following element 
Repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a functional solution which will work with an array of any iterable value (not just strings), and uses object identity comparison for value equality:

```js
function findCommon (iterA, iterB) {
  const common = new Set();
  const uniqueB = new Set(iterB);
  for (const value of iterA) if (uniqueB.has(value)) common.add(value);
  return common;
}

function findAllCommon (arrayOfIter) {
  if (arrayOfIter.length === 0) return [];
  let common = new Set(arrayOfIter[0]);
  for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfIter.length; i += 1) {
    common = findCommon(common, arrayOfIter[i]);
  }
  return [...common];
}

const arr = ['robin', 'rohit', 'roy'];

const result = findAllCommon(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999821/i-have-a-array-of-string-have-to-find-all-the-common-character-present-from-all/74000033?noredirect=1#comment130659935_74000033) @Ry- Good point — I was thinking about saving cycles on (potentially lots of) duplicate values, but I guess they're all already iterated by the `Set` constructor anyway. (I updated the answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's seems the right approach to use Set constructor here I have tested the above code and it's working perfectly fine also advantage with Set don't need additional affort to get unique character from word.

Comment: In above code you also using multi loops. One loop for calling find common() function and other inside the findCommon() function so as we can see other answers also achieving the same result by counting char with two loops. So it's going to make any impact on execution time can you please explain it a little bit thanks.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999821/i-have-a-array-of-string-have-to-find-all-the-common-character-present-from-all/74000033?noredirect=1#comment130660801_74000033) @JitendraPathak See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999821/i-have-a-array-of-string-have-to-find-all-the-common-character-present-from-all/74000033?noredirect=1#comment130659314_73999821) — after reading it, I composed this answer as an implementation. `findCommon` returns the intersection of sets A and B, and `findAllCommon` repeats that operation with each element of the input array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ["roooooobin","rohit","roy"];

const commonChars = (arr) => {
  const charsCount = arr.reduce((sum, word) => {
    const wordChars = word.split('').reduce((ws, c) => {
      ws[c] = 1;
      return ws;
    }, {});
    Object.keys(wordChars).forEach((c) => {
      sum[c] = (sum[c] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return sum;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(charsCount).filter(key => charsCount[key] === arr.length);
}

console.log(commonChars(arr));
```

Comment: you're basically counting how much times a letter is repeated **without** assuming a letter may be repeated in a single string in the array: eg=["rooob","rooon","roool"] which your answer would only say r instead of r AND o

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 1 liner if anyone interested

```
  new Set(arr.map(d => [...d]).flat(Infinity).reduce((ac,d) => {(new RegExp(`(?:.*${d}.*){${arr.length}}`)).test(arr) && ac.push(d); return ac},[])) //{r,o}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter which way you choose, you will still need to count all characters, you cannot get around `O(n*2)` as far as I know.

```js
arr=["robin","rohit","roy"];
    
let commonChars = sumCommonCharacters(arr);

function sumCommonCharacters(arr) {
  data = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       for(let char in arr[i]) {
         let key = arr[i][char];
         data[key] = (data[key] != null) ? data[key]+1 : 1;
       }
  }
  return data;
}
console.log(commonChars);
```

Comment: The above code will return o,r,a even other word not have common characters. Eg: ["ooo","rrrr","aaa"]

Comment: Yes, I did not filter those out because of laziness. I wanted to show the procedure I choose and to prove a point that 0(n*2) stays. But you're correct, I should have filtered away uncommon characters.

Comment: I think the code with Set constructor is more efficient as mention by @jsejcksn what's your opinion.

Comment: I totally agree, @jsejcksn code is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the idea is to count the amount of times each letter occurs **but** only counting 1 letter per string

```js
let arr=["robin","rohit","roy"];

function commonLetter(array){
  var count={} //object used for counting letters total
  for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    //looping through the array
    const cache={} //same letters only counted once here
    for(let j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
      //looping through the string
      let letter=array[i][j]
      if(cache[letter]!==true){
        //if letter not yet counted in this string
        cache[letter]=true //well now it is counted in this string
        count[letter]=(count[letter]||0)+1
        //I don't say count[letter]++ because count[letter] may not be defined yet, hence (count[letter]||0)
      }
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(count)
  .filter(letter=>count[letter]===array.length)
  .join(',')
}

//usage
console.log(commonLetter(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to check for the occurrences of each character. 
 loop on the words in the array, then loop on the chars of each word.

```js
let arr = ["robin","rohit","roy"];

const restWords = arr.slice(1);
const result = arr[0].split('').filter(char => 
    restWords.every(word => word.includes(char)))
const uniqueChars = Array.from(new Set(result));

console.log(uniqueChars);
```

Comment: The above code will return o,r,a even other word not have common characters. Eg: ["ooo","rrrr","aaa"]

Comment: @JitendraPathak you're right, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Input ["abc", "bcd", "cbad"]

```
let arr = ["abcc", "bcd", "cbad"]
let arrLength = arr.length
let finalArr = arr.join("").split("").sort()
var obj = {};
var max = [];
for (var i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
    (obj[finalArr[i]]) ? obj[finalArr[i]] += 1: obj[finalArr[i]] = 1;
    if (obj[finalArr[i]] == arrLength) {
        max.push(finalArr[i])
    }
}
console.log(max)
```

> Output ["b","c"]